# Removing the gubbins that installing gnome adds

Tags: 14.04, gnome, cleanup

I was troubleshooting issues a while back, and found myself installing the gnome desktop environment instead of the unity one.

I've since removed everything I could think of, but when I open a terminal, it still has a horrible 'skin' with a black background and a red title bar.

I'm not hugely concerned about this, but I do wonder if there's anything else that's been installed/modified as a result of installing gnome that I haven't managed to revert.

Is there a list of packages/changes that are added when installing gnome somewhere?
Does anyone have a magic command that will remove it all? :)

(I'm running ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8 months later, I finally found out what was causing the terminal to look so horrible - terminator got installed. Removing this brought back the much nicer looking "terminal" that I'm used to.